# International Travel with US Passport where the middle name is misspelled?

Tags: usa, passports

I recently got my newborn's US passport.  However, her middle name seems to have been misspelled. There is an 'A' where there shouldn't be. We have travel to Canada coming up in the next couple of months, and I am not sure if this mistake is going to cause us issues.

The Department of State website says they will correct the error free of charge, but that means we'll be passportless for another 2 to 3 months, which may affect our travel plans

Comment: The only issue I can imagine is if you had to prove you and your partner are the parents. The parent's names aren't in the passport, so you would show the birth certificate. But the middle names on the passport and birth certificate would disagree.

Answer (score 3):

For all practical purposes, the misspelled name on the passport *is* her legal name for travel, Canada won't know any different.  So just use it to travel now and get the passport corrected after you have come back.

Also, for what it's worth, middle names are usually ignored completely for airline ID matching purposes.